# With WinJS.UI.ListView, how to disable click animation when in snapview

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime

Using the "Grid" example in vs2012 RC, the grid turns into a ListView when you are in snapped view.  In my application, I don't want the itemInvoked page method called when an items is selected in snapview.  I also don't want the animation on the item making the user think something will happen.  I know how to disable iteminvoked (see below) but not sure how to get rid of the animation when the item is selected (invoked).

```
   itemInvoked: function (args) {
        if (appView.value != appViewState.snapped) {
            var listView = document.getElementById("groupdetaillistId").winControl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that WinJS actually does some inline styling with the animations.  There is no way to disable it using CSS.  However, we can use the power of JavaScript to just reset what the function does.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

var origFunc = WinJS.UI._SelectionMode.prototype.togglePressed;

function handleResize(evt) {

    var currentViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value;

    if (currentViewState === 2) {
        WinJS.UI._SelectionMode.prototype.togglePressed = function (add) {};
    }
    else {
        WinJS.UI._SelectionMode.prototype.togglePressed = origFunc;
    }
}
```

Found this link which is what led me to this solution when I saw your problem.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/847cefe9-30f6-4f05-96ad-26ece31b77c5

All this code is in global space.
Register for the resize event

```
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
```

Store the original function in a variable

```
var origFunc = WinJS.UI._SelectionMode.prototype.togglePressed;
```

Handle the resize event

```
function handleResize(evt) {
```

Get the current view state

```
    var currentViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value;
```

If we are in snapped mode set the function to empty

```
    if (currentViewState === 2) {
        WinJS.UI._SelectionMode.prototype.togglePressed = function (add) {};
    }
```

Otherwise, set it back to the WinJS version

```
    else {
        WinJS.UI._SelectionMode.prototype.togglePressed = origFunc;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Curious to know if this worked for you.  By adding the above code to a new Grid App template in the default.js in global space I was able to get the results you were after.

Comment: Yup, worked!  thanks.  It does not quite get to the full solution but it does do everything i asked.  Now, when I touch an item in snapped view, it does not animate but the item does flash in a way that the user might think  something is suppose to happen.  To be honest, I'm not 100% sure what the correct behavior should be.  definitely it should not animiate and your solution elegantly fixes that.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the following WinJS.UI.ListView properties and it will make the items not clickable along w/ removing the "clicking" animations:

```
selectionMode: 'none'
tapBehavior: 'none'
swipeBehavior:'none'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211851.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700733.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700730.aspx

Answer (score 1):

B Z is on the right path. The ListView has native mechanisms to deal with this that don't require hacky Javascript. I would have upvoted B Z and downvoted Chad Carter, but I don't have any reputation points. I guess that's what you get for being a silent, non-subscribed observer of StackOverflow for a decade :/